# Disable this week and future dates Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have modified the calendar to select weeks and show in a textbox which works great.

I am trying to disable the current week as well as future dates but don't know how to, I tried this but it doesnt work

```
$("#selector").datepicker({
    maxDate: 0
});
```

My fiddle is below

```js
$(function() {
var startDate;
var endDate;

var selectCurrentWeek = function() {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').addClass('ui-state-active')
    }, 1);
}

$('.week-picker').datepicker( {
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
        endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
        var dateFormat = inst.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat;
        $("#txtWeekPicker").val($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, startDate, inst.settings )+" - "+$.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, endDate, inst.settings ));
        
        selectCurrentWeek();
    },
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var cssClass = '';
        if(date >= startDate && date <= endDate)
            cssClass = 'ui-datepicker-current-day';
        
        selectCurrentWeek();
        return [true, cssClass];
    },
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
        selectCurrentWeek();
    }
});

$('.ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mousemove', function() { $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover'); });
$('.ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mouseleave', function() { $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover'); });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="week-picker"></div>
<br /><br />
 <input type="text" id="txtWeekPicker" class="week-picker" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the new HTML5 week input type.

```
<input type="week" max="week number">
```

However, it's hard to style and you would also have to figure out the JS to calculate current week. Also, no Firefox support or pre-IE 12.